# Растягивание родительского блока по ширине одного из дочерних

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Нужно организовать подпись под фотографией. Размеры всего блока должны автоматически задаваться исходя из размеров фотографии и подписи. При этом на ширину .wrap должна зависеть только ширина фотографии. Вариант с width: inherit не прокатывает. Ширина должна задаваться только в 1м месте - у фотографии.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   <ul>
     <li>
       <img src="/1.png" width=50 height=50>
        <div>
          <span>Я текст и от моего размера не должна зависеть ширина .wrap</span>
        </div>
      <li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/MghzK/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день! Держите:

```
li {
  width:1%;
  display:table;
}
```

Comment: Позволю себе подправить:  
    width:1px;

Спс, работает, но мне кажется метод не достаточно "чистым". Всё же таблицы для таблиц.